# Amcharts4 Maps with custom geojson data only show one feature (geographical region) out of many?

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I was trying to create a map with amcharts4's custom maps using [this](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/creating-custom-maps/) tutorial. It works perfectly when I used a map from amcharts geojson library. But when I add a different map like [this map](https://github.com/thejeshgn/srilanka/blob/master/electoral_districts_map/LKA_electrol_districts.geojson). It only shows the last feature of geojson feature collection. I tried adding a `id` as described here in this [issue](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/1438) but It gave me the same result. Can anybody help me to get this work?

here is a code pen demostrating the issue: https://codepen.io/sankhax/pen/YzwLdJy

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GeoJSON is still missing the `id` property, which needs to be unique for each feature in your JSON's `features` array; the tutorial states that it needs to be in the top-level of the feature object, but having an `id` in the `properties` object also works, as you can see in the other map in your codepen. The value stored in  `electoralDistrictCode` from your properties data is a good candidate for an `id`:

```
[{
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": "MON",
    "properties": {
        "electoralDistrictCode": "MON",
        "electoralDistrict": "Monaragala",
        // ...
    },
    "geometry": {/* ... */}
},{
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": "ANU",
    "properties": {
        "electoralDistrictCode": "ANU",
        "electoralDistrict": "Anuradhapura",
        // ...
    },
    "geometry": {/* ... */}
},
// ...
]
```

Once you add this to your JSON, your map will render correctly in AmCharts v4. Demo below, using a manual AJAX request to mutate the JSON to work with the library:

```js
var map = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4maps.MapChart);
// indonesia geojson
fetch(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GayanSandaruwan/elections/master/electoral_with_results.geojson"
)
  .then(function(resp) {
    if (resp.ok) {
      return resp.json();
    }
    throw new Error("Unable to fetch json data");
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    //add the missing id property before assigning it to the map
    data.features.forEach(function (feature) {
      feature.id = feature.properties.electoralDistrictCode;
    });
    map.geodata = data;
  });
map.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();
var polygonSeries = new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries();
polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;
map.series.push(polygonSeries);
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/maps.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. :)  I simplified above map using http://mapshaper.org/ since it was 4MB+ in size, however, my new map is showing the same old error. here is the updated code pen https://codepen.io/sankhax/pen/YzwLdJy could you please help me?

Comment: Your coordinates need to be in [clockwise order](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/custom-polygons-on-map-chart/#Final_word) (see note above Final word). Your points are in counter-clockwise order. Also note that you still don't have IDs set in your JSON.

Comment: I am using your implementation codepen.io/sankhax/pen/YzwLdJy  here. So you appending the ids later. =D I am following  https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/creating-custom-maps/ this tutorial to reduce the file size of the map. It doesn't mention the fact that coordinates need to be clockwise. :( is there way to fix it using mapshaper.org ?

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it working by using https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-rewind thanks again for your help. =D